# How can i get content from other site than current in Umbraco?

Tags: umbraco

I am trying to create a news section on my frontpage (Home) umbraco site. 
My idea is to keep the news content apart from the site content in a folder like this:

- Home

  - Page2
  - Page3
- News

  - News item 1
  - News item 2

But how can I get the news content into my (home) page, when it's not in the same folder?

Please help.

Comment: What version of umbraco?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using XSLT then you'd do this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::root/News/NewsItem">
  <!-- do whatever here -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

If you're doing Razor syntax, then use:

```
@foreach (var newsitem in Library.NodeById(-1).Descendants("News").ChildrenAsList) {
  // Your processing/rendering code in here
}
```